# How to get previous LI in multi-level UL/LI elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following html code:

```
<ul>
  <li>Parameter1</li>
  <li>Group1
    <ul>
      <li>Parameter2</li>
      <li>Parameter3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Parameter4</li>
  <li>Group2
    <ul>
      <li>Parameter5</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And when I trigger onClick method on any of the LI elements, I need to get closest previous LI element.

If I click `Parameter4` I need `Parameter3` element.
If I click `Parameter5` I need `Group2` element.

I know the basics of prev(), closest(), find(), but I am not able to make it work.

`element.prev('li')` ignores nested LIs in UL

I think I am able to write the logic in words: I need previous LI element `element.prev('li')` and if this element has UL inside, I want last LI in that. If it has no UL, return the `prev('li')` that we started with.

Thank you.

Comment: Only `li` can be a direct child of `ul`

Comment: Is the edited code correct now? I think my problem still persists. How to get `Parameter3` when I click `Parameter4` and still get `Parameter4` when I click `Group2`?

Comment: I think I am able to write the logic in words: I need previous LI element `element.prev('li')` and if this element has UL inside, I want last LI in that. If it has no UL, return the `prev('li')` that we started with.

Comment: Or in another words, I just need direct closest previous LI element in code (I don't care about parents, childs, siblings).

Comment: @Neon : please check my answer

Comment: @Neon see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey you can do something like this.. i tested this locally and it's working...

```
<ul>
  <li>Parameter1</li>
  <li>Group1
    <ul>
      <li>Parameter2</li>
      <li>Parameter3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Parameter4</li>
  <li>Group2
    <ul>
      <li>Parameter5</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and jQuery like this

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $('li').on('click',function(event) {

    event.stopPropagation();

    if ($(this).children("ul").length > 0) {

       if($(this).prev('li').length > 0) {

         console.log($(this).prev('li').text());

       }


     } else if ($(this).prev('li').length > 0 && $(this).prev('li').children("ul").length > 0 ) {

       console.log($(this).prev('li').children("ul").find("li:last").text());

     } else if($(this).prev('li').length > 0) {

          console.log($(this).prev('li').clone().children().remove().end().text());

     } else if ($(this).is(":first-child"))  {

        console.log($(this).parent('ul').parent('li').clone().children().remove().end().text().trim());

     } else {

        console.log($(this).closest('ul').prev('li').text());

     }

     });
    </script>
```

**PS**: Don't forget too include jQuery

Comment: Could be close, but please, check my updated HTML code and I need only 'text' of the LI element. Your code returns me text of more previous LI together. Here's the fiddle with new HTML code https://jsfiddle.net/Neonovic/cswycvff/

Comment: i made fiddle for pls check it out and tell me if something missing or what you want https://jsfiddle.net/arpan2010/apvkras5/

Comment: I have solved the problem differently, but for the sake of choosing the right answer, I would like to cooperate with you. But have you really tested the code? Because few clicks tells me, it doesn't work at all like I described. I am not sure if you want to spent more time on this. If yes, I can talk about it more.

Comment: tell me what you want. i think i misunderstood something

Comment: Can you read the original question? I have to repeat myself. When I click `parameter4` I need to get `Parameter3`. When I click `Parameter5` I need `Group2`. Really repeating myself. You could read it first time.

Comment: i update fiddle for you please if this will help you https://jsfiddle.net/arpan2010/apvkras5/3/

Comment: Seems to work like I wanted. Make it please official. Update the answer or make a new one and I will flag it as "Accepted answer". Nice work. Thank you @patelarpan.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$('ul li').click(function(e) {
var element = $(this);
if(element.prevAll('li').length > 0) {
   element.prev('li').text();
} else {
   element.closest('ul').parent('li').text();
}  
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

Comment: Something tells me, this kind of answer could be close. I am going to test and play with it.

Comment: If I am testing right, this doesn't gets me `Parameter3` when I click `Parameter4`. It gives me `Group1` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can try testing each element to see if the previous has a list and take the last element or if the element is part of a parent list and take the parent list value:

```js
$('li').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation()
  var prev = $(e.target).prev();
  var parent = $(e.target).parent().closest('li');
  
  if (prev.find('ul li').length) {
    console.log(prev.find('ul li:last').text());
  } else
  if (parent.length && !prev.length) {
    console.log(parent.clone().find('ul').remove().end().text())
  } else {
    console.log(prev.text());
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Parameter1</li>
  <li>Group1
    <ul>
      <li>Parameter2</li>
      <li>Parameter3</li>
      <li>GroupX
    <ul>
      <li>ParameterX</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Parameter4</li>
  <li>Group2
    <ul>
      <li>Parameter5</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have come with this solution. Took the liberty to use jQuery myself. And there is some duplicated code here, but it's just the idea.

```
$('li').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if($(this).prev('li').length == 0) {
        if($(this).parent().parent().prev('li').has('ul').length) {
            console.log($(this).parent().parent().prev('li').children('ul').find('li:last').text());
        } else {
            console.log($(this).parent().parent().prev('li').text());
        }
    } else {
         if($(this).prev('li').has('ul').length) {
            console.log($(this).prev('li').children('ul').find('li:last').text());
         } else {
            console.log($(this).prev('li').text());
         }
    }  
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul li').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    var self = $(this);
    if (self.prev().is('li') && !self.prev('li').children().is('ul')) {
      console.log(self.prev('li').text());
    }
    else if (self.prev().is('li') && self.prev('li').children().is('ul')) {
      console.log(self.prev('li').children('ul').children('li').last().text());
    } 
    else if (self.parent('ul').parent().is('li') && !self.prev().is('li')) {
      console.log(self.parent('ul').parent('li').prev('li').text());
    } else {
      console.log('no previous element');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Parameter1</li>
  <li>Group1
    <ul>
      <li>Parameter2</li>
      <li>Parameter3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li>Parameter4</li>
  <li>Group2
    <ul>
      <li>Parameter5</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: This doesn't reflect the HTML structure the OP has. Even though it's flawed, the point is that OP wants to use a *multi-level* list

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the HTML structure he used was not valid.I thought he misspelled it.My bad

Comment: That's right, but like I said, the point is that OP wants to use a multi-level structure. Once he's fixed the HTML, this won't work.

Comment: I'd be happy to remove the downvote if you update the answer to reflect the OPs updated HTML sample

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan : is this what he desired?

Comment: Almost, but not quite. I'll remove the downvote anyway as it's a more valid attempt.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan is it still not valid?

Comment: Your code fails on this requirement: `If I click Parameter4 I need Parameter3 element. If I click Parameter5 I need Group2 element.`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan now?

Comment: Why are you asking me? Get the OP to check - it's his question

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan sorry brother ! But that downvote hurts me.

Comment: I already removed mine - that one is someone else's I'm afraid